# Ошибка установки пакетов через pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Купил я orangepi zero на 512 MB для маленьких вк ботов, вот только даже установить библиотеки не удается

О системе

- OS: Armbian bionic
- Версия python: python 3.6

установленные пакеты:

```
Package             Version
-----------------------------
command-not-found   0.3
iotop               0.6
pip                 20.0.2
pygobject           3.26.1
python-apt          1.6.5+ubuntu0.2
python-dateutil     2.8.1
setuptools          45.2.0
six                 1.14.0
unattended-upgrades 0.1
wheel               0.34.2
```

Результат установки библиотеки bokeh (взята для примера)

```
python3 -m pip install bokeh
Collecting bokeh
  Using cached bokeh-1.4.0.tar.gz (32.4 MB)
Collecting six>=1.5.2
  Using cached six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting PyYAML>=3.10
  Using cached PyYAML-5.3.tar.gz (268 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting Jinja2>=2.7
  Using cached Jinja2-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.7.1
  Using cached numpy-1.18.1.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpbj4i9nl2
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-rk9ai8mh/numpy
    Complete output (222 lines):
    Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random/_bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6
    creating build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy
    creating build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifc
    Could not locate executable lf95
    Could not locate executable pgfortran
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable fort
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable g95
    Could not locate executable pathf95
    Could not locate executable nagfor
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
    creating build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core
    creating build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src
    creating build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h
      adding 'build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
    None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
    building library "npysort" sources
    creating build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/common
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h
      adding 'build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/common' to include_dirs.
    creating build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/timsort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/heapsort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/binsearch.c
    None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h', 'build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h', 'build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h']
    building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_tests" sources
    creating build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/multiarray
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c
    building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_umath" sources
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arraytypes.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/multiarray/lowlevel_strided_loops.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/multiarray/nditer_templ.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c
    creating build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/umath
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/umath/funcs.inc
      adding 'build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/umath' to include_dirs.
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-armv7l-3.6/numpy/core/src/umath/simd.inc
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    /tmp/pip-install-rk9ai8mh/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    /tmp/pip-install-rk9ai8mh/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    /tmp/pip-install-rk9ai8mh/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    /tmp/pip-install-rk9ai8mh/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    /tmp/pip-install-rk9ai8mh/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    /usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: [Errno 28] No space left on device
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpbj4i9nl2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Большинство пакетов с расширениями на С, которые выложены на PyPI, не скомпилированы под ARM - советую добавить репозиторий piwheels, чтобы не компилировать тяжелые библиотеки на дохлом процессоре: `pip install bokeh --extra-index-url=https://piwheels.org/simple`, есть немаленький шанс, что установка пробежит куда быстрее, чем без piwheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вот же ясно написано:

```
error: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

У Вас на SD карточке места нет.

Comment: Но ведь доступно ещё 13 гигабайт```  df -h 
Файл.система Размер Использовано Дост Использовано% Cмонтировано в udev 178M 0 178M 0% /dev tmpfs 50M 2,3M 47M 5% /run /dev/mmcblk0p1 15G 1,1G 13G 8% /```

Comment: Это Вы (наверное) смотрите **после** завершения попытки установки. А памяти не хватило **во время**! Подозреваю, что там создавалась куча временных файлов из распаковываемых архивов.

Comment: Хм, ну тогда, так полагаю, нужно либо увеличить /tmp раздел, либо явно указать расположение tmp в папке пользователя. В любом случае спасибо за ответ